# Here is an interactive Suduko Solver which could use some 'tuning'

Tags: google-sheets-api

[Here's a link to the file. Feel free to copy to your own directory.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VFo9Gmt4Tc7GEXoswG2wHSZrxIhm5ficQuiDYfwuZZc/edit?usp=sharing)
This file is a copy of an Excel version which I built 5 or 10 years ago. The Excel version runs in lightning speed - i.e. one step to a Full Solution. I wish I could say the same about this Google Sheet version. I would appreciate any advice on techniques for speeding it up.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see the shared Spreadsheet. Can you check it?

Comment: Can you provide the script of your Google version?

Comment: Apologies: I forgot to make the sharing Public. This should work now. Let me know if you have any ither problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve the puzzles faster, you have to improve your algorithm.

Right now you are using a backtracking strategy that is very slow, since it basically brute-forces solutions.

You can read more on those algorithms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms#Techniques).

Another point for improvement is your data get/sets. If you do all your getting and setting on the data of the sheet at once you will have some performance improvements.

Another solution would be to have a more potent machine execute and return the solved puzzle to you via an HTTP call. You could do this with the URLFetchApp from Apps Script.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, ZektorH. I think you answered my ultimate question: How equivalent is Google Sheets + Javascript code to MS Excel + VBA? The answer: It can perform comparable actions but beware the limits of the architecture, particularly with respect to addressability and execution speed.